# How to mock the Mongoose model for find with populate

Tags: mongoose, jestjs

I am having the below Node JS with mongoose code. I have to mock this query to throw an error in my JEST unit testing. Can anyone help me with how to achieve it?

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const data = await users
                .find(filter, porjectFields)
                .populate({
                    path: 'user.address',
                    populate: {
                        path: 'location'
                    }
                })
                .lean();
            resolve(data);
        } catch (err) {
            logger.error(
                `Error in user : ${err}`
            );
            reject(err);
        }
    });
```

I tried to mock like below, but i am getting error on lean function.

```
users.find = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
                populate: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ name: 'hello' }),
                lean: true
            }));
```

**Error:**

*TypeError: users.find(...).populate(...).lean is not a function*

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea you just missed that lean is also a function.

```
users.find = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
                populate: () => ({ lean: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ name: 'hello' }) })
            }));
```